# Magento 2 - Visual Merchandiser Smart Categories with multi-select attributes

Tags: php, magento2, multi-select

Why was support for multiselect attributes in Magento 2 explicitly removed from the collection of allowed attributes for the visual merchandisers "Smart Categories"?  We had used this in Magento 1 but need a way to get this same functionality back in Magento 2.

This is where the attributes are explicitly filtered out from the collection.

```
vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/Model/Config/Source/AllowedAttributes.php
```

I can remove this like so: (obviously I would do this via a plugin to actually implement this feature)

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $entityTypeId = $this->type->loadByCode(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY)->getId();
    if ($entityTypeId) {
        $collection = $this->attribute->getCollection()
            ->removeAllFieldsFromSelect()
            ->addFieldToSelect('attribute_code', 'value')
            ->addFieldToSelect('frontend_label', 'label')
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', ['eq' = $entityTypeId]);
// removes multi: ->addFieldToFilter('frontend_input', ['neq' => 'multiselect']);
        $attributes = $collection->toArray();
        if (isset($attributes['items'])) {
            $this->options = $attributes['items'];
        }
    }
    return $this->options;
}
```

However I feel this is only the tip of the ice berg. What display logic is needed to properly parse these attributes and join the corresponding products to the collection?